# Download file at a particular location and not in the default download folder without any dialogue box

Tags: c#

Below is my code in C#:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fi.Name);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileCurrentPath);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You can only transmit the file, where to store it is a decision of the client.

Comment: To make this more complete, you might want to mention **why** this isn't permitted, and why it's a really bad idea. Just in case. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Well, I think that anyone can understand the implications that would have that an external server could control your file system silently and remotely as  op is asking to do...

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking the same but was little bit confused.